# Native file transfer plugin doesn't create directory in android 10 and android 11 using Ionic with capacitor

Tags: android, ionic-framework

When i tried to download the file using Native file transfer plugin Then I got below error

```
vendor.js:48185 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): FileError: {"code":12,"message":"PATH_EXISTS_ERR"}
    at resolvePromise (polyfills.js:1291)
    at polyfills.js:1198
    at polyfills.js:1214
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (polyfills.js:436)
    at Object.onInvoke (vendor.js:70411)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (polyfills.js:435)
    at Zone.run (polyfills.js:196)
    at polyfills.js:1354
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (polyfills.js:470)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (vendor.js:70398)
12:09
FileTransferError {code: 1, source: 'https://standardebooks.org/ebooks/robert-louis-ste…loads/robert-louis-stevenson_treasure-island.epub', target: 'file:///storage/emulated/0/Universal-Book/robert-louis-stevenson_treasure-island.epub', http_status: 200, body: null, …}
```

File downloading is work for Android Version 7 but above its showing above error

Comment: Please mention and discuss the error. code":12,"message":"PATH_EXISTS_ERR

Comment: share your code

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you have permissions to write directly in "file:///storage/emulated/0/" directory. Take a look at possible locations you can use to store your files: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/10.x/reference/cordova-plugin-file/index.html